# SQL Grouping calculations

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I have this grouping problem that I can't seem to figure out. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Let's say I have a table like this:

```
Name     Passed?     PlanID      Plan
-----------------------------------------
Tom         1          1         Math
Tom         1          1         Reading
Tom         0          2         Math
Tom         0          2         Reading 
Tom         0          3         Math
Tom         0          3         Reading
Bobby       1          1         Math
Bobby       0          1         Reading
Bobby       1          2         Math
Bobby       1          2         Reading
Bobby       0          3         Math
Bobby       0          3         Reading
Linda       0          1         Math
Linda       1          1         Reading
Linda       0          2         Math
Linda       1          2         Reading
Linda       1          3         Math
Linda       1          3         Reading
```

What I want to accomplish is something like this:

```
Name     Passed?     PlanID
---------------------------
Tom         1          1
Bobby       1          2
Linda       1          3
```

So basically, if the first planID hasn't been passed, look at the second one. If that one hasn't been passed, look at the third one. The issue I'm running into is that all the PlanIDs will be 3 or 1 or all the values in the Passed column will be 0.

I've tried a query like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN MIN(Passed?) = 1
    THEN MIN(PlanID)
    ELSE MAX(PlanID)
    END
```

I realize that the max and min will only yield a 3 or 1, but I'm not sure how else to go about it. Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention that if a person has passed a planID, then the rest of the planIDs should read as passed. So since Bobby didn't pass both plans the first time, he must take it again. Since he passed the second time, he does not have to take it a third time. A person must pass both plan to count as passed, if that makes sense. I've added a couple more rows to hopefully communicate what I'm thinking of better. I may be making this a bit too confusing for myself as well.

Comment: Can one pass multiple plan ID?

Comment: How to treat the ones that never pass?

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Passed = '1'`?

Comment: @hashbrown Hopefully my edit adds clarity. A person should remain passed if said person has passed before.

Comment: @lrb The ones that never pass will carry over to the next planID, if a new one were to be created. So if they remain not passed, they must take the next outlined courses

Comment: @AaronD Sorry, I should've added a bit more information. With the WHERE Passed = '1', I think it would bring multiple planIDs vs. the single one I'm looking for

Comment: @Marco Should the ones with a sum of zeros still show up in the resulting dataset, if they have not passed a plan do you still want the name?

Comment: @lrb 0's should show up only for the most recent PlanID. No need for the name, just the planID since the planID is a grouping of the plans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a possibility that we may see multiple passes for the same name and you just want to pick up the first one, use below query:

```
select pass.name, pass.passed, pass.planID
from 
(Select name, passed, planID
from table
where passed = 1) pass, 
(Select name, min(planID) planId
from table
where passed = 1) min
where pass.planID= min.planID and pass.name = min.name
```

If there could only be one pass, you can simply select the pass:

```
select * from table where Passed = 1
```

Comment: This is the one that helped me clarify what I needed to do, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if return just passed? = 1

```
select * from table where Passed? = 1
```

returns as you want

Comment: Although it would work for my example above, it will not work for my query. Sorry, I should've added more information to begin with, but with that WHERE clause, I believe it would bring in multiple PlanIDs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` subquery to check if exist smaller `planID` for this `Name`.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable T1
 WHERE Passed = 1 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM YourTable T2
                   WHERE T1.Name = T2.Name
                     AND T1.planID > T2.planID
                     AND T2.Passed  = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, count(Passed?) as passedTotal from table where Passed? = 1 and passedTotal=2 group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

This one was a little tricky because with what little info was given I considered and assumed the following edge cases:

1. A student can fail skip plans (fail plan 7 and pass plan 8)
2. A student can skip plans (take plan 5 but not 4,3,2,1) --> Not sequential
3. A student can pass no plans (attempt plan 1 x times, while still being included in the output)
4. A student can place into a mid point (start at plan 6)
5. A student can skip forward and backward

Also, this is assuming that the latest work is last in "natural order" (when the record was inserted, not PlanID).

The below should work all cases given.

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Passed=MAX(Passed),
    PlanID=MAX(PlanID)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Flag=DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name,Passed DESC) ,
        Name,
        Passed,
        PlanID  
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Name,   
            PlanID,
            Passed
        FROM
            Table
    )AS X
)AS Y
WHERE 
    Flag=1
GROUP BY 
    Name
```